# Send message to Facebook inbox with Java 7 and Spring

Tags: java, spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to send URL to Facebook inbox using Java or Spring without providing Facebook login screen.

1. Is it able to do this without providing Facebook login?
2. Can I use Spring social Facebook to do that?

I have read lot of article but I could not find right details. Can anyone guide me to right direction step by step?

Comment: There is no API to directly send messages to users out of the blue. Depending on what your actual specific use case is, other stuff like the Messenger Platform might be applicable - or not.

Comment: You can't send URL to Facebook inbox without logging in. You need to make your app request for an `authkey` from facebook to a specific user and get a permission send something. Remember when Facebook remove all the third party apps that can access to the inbox of a user for security purposes. That was 2015.

Comment: Yes, can I send message to messenger?. Not directly Facebook.